# Expected waiting time with $m$ tellers and $n$ customers at a bank

Tags: probability

Suppose we have the following scenario:

> There are $n$ customers at a bank who wish to speak with bank tellers.
>   There are $m$ tellers, and each of the $n$ customers is willing to
>   speak to any of the $m$ tellers. Rather than forming individual lines
>   for each teller, the customers form a single queue, and the next
>   person in line goes to the next available teller. The amount of time
>   each customer spends with the teller is exponentially distributed with
>   mean $\lambda$. Compute the expected waiting time for the person next
>   in line in the queue. (You may neglect the time it takes someone to
>   walk from the queue to the teller.)

Anyone know how to solve this? This isn't a homework question, but rather a question from a class that I took back in college (it is of particular relevance at the moment as I am needing to compute this sort of a quantity for a piece of software that I am writing).

Comment: First in line or last in line?

Comment: First. I would assume that to compute the expected time for the last, you could simply apply linearity of expectation.

Comment: The waiting time for the first in line is the minimum of $m$ independent exponentials. This has exponential distribution mean $\lambda/m$.

Answer (score 1):

Because you imply there are people queued, I assume $n > m.$
Each person in line begins service when the next teller
becomes available. That happens at rate $m/\lambda,$
so the mean waiting time *in the queue* for the next customer
is $\lambda/m.$ The mean time until that customer *finishes*
being served is $\lambda/m + \lambda.$

*Notes:* (1) To avoid potential confusion, texts on queueing models typically
use $\lambda$ for the *rate* of arrival of new customers, and
$\mu$ for the service *rate.*  Means of exponential distributions
are the reciprocals of rates.

(2) The distribution of the waiting time for the minimum of
$k$ exponential waiting times (next available server) is 
exponential with a rate of $k$ times the rate for
individual servers (assuming all rates equal).

(3) If you want to look for more on this topic, I suggest you
read about $M/M/k$ queues. The first M stands for (Markov,
memoryless, or exponential) interarrival times, the second
M for exponential service times, and the k for the number
of servers.